# Yii2 - Return Validation Error as json_encode

Tags: php, yii2

I'm needing some guidance as to how I can collect the validation error from multiple models and return them as json_encode if there are any errors.  I've tried the following, but it breaks into the debugger in which I can see the error (cause) which I don't understand why it isn't being handled and returned.

Here's the relevant part of my controller.

```
$validClient = $model->validate();
if (! $validClient) {
    $flashMsg = '<strong>Client Model Not Valid!</strong>';
    $jsonMsg = implode("Client: ", $model->errors);
}
// Validate the Contacts Model
$validContacts = Model::validateMultiple($modelsContacts);
if (! $validContacts) {
    $flashMsg .= '<strong>Contacts Model Not Valid!</strong>';
    $jsonMsg .= implode("Contacts: ", $modelsContacts->errors); 
}
// Validate the Price List Model
$validPrices = Model::validateMultiple($modelsPrices);
if (! $validPrices) {
    $flashMsg .= '<strong>Price List Model Not Valid!</strong>';
    $jsonMsg .= implode("Price List: ", $modelsPrices->errors);
}

$valid = $validClient && $validContacts && $validPrices;
if ($valid) {
    //proceed with the transaction
} else {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $flashMsg);
    echo json_encode(['status' => 'Error', 'message' => $jsonMsg]);
}
```

The issue has to do with a required field not being filled out, and that's fine, but I just don't understand what I am missing so it gets handled quietly and return the json string instead of erring the way it currently is.

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: The browser goes into debug mode and if I review the flagged error I see

responseText: "<pre>Exception (Integrity constraint violation) &#039;yii\\db\\IntegrityException&#039; with message &#039;SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`utap`.`clients`, CONSTRAINT `clients_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`CurrencyCode`) REFERENCES `lst_currencies` (`CurrencyCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)\nThe SQL being executed was: UPDATE `clients` SET `CityId`=955, `ProvId`=25, `CountryId`=2, `CurrencyCode`=&#039;&#039;, ....

Comment: Your request is Ajax?

Comment: add your actual controller action as you are using what i recon is that you dont have to use the `echo json_encode()` if you are using the latest version for Yii2 you should get the error for even a simple ajax request , you should set the response format inside the action and return the array which will be responsed as JSON automagically by Yii, please add the actual  code the way you are using it.

Comment: Muhammad, could you point me to a sample of what you are referring to so I can review this approach and learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to update a record with a value for (`CurrencyCode`) that is constrained by the database since it's referenced as a foreign key by the `clients` table.

Make sure that CurrencyCode is passed as a legal value AND that it exists as a foreign key.

This error is thrown by the database connection, not by validating the model in Yii.

Comment: But that's the whole point, I can fix the underlying issue (and will), but why isn't the validation catching the error and sending the json_encode  back?  Why is it proceeding with the transaction?  What am I doing wrong to trap the error in my code?

Comment: Base on the code you provided my guess is that somewhere, before or in the validation, the `update` query is being called. So the database connection is complaining before your code gets to the `json_encode`.

Comment: Thank you.  You got me pointed in the right direction.  The issue is that my dropdown, when nothing is selected, return an empty string rather than a NULL value, thus the validator see a value and so it passes through to the processing and then bombs because the empty string isn't in the related table.  I added some code to my controller to convert "" = NULL and all is good in the world again.